# I thought answer of these time complexity is O(n) but it is wrong. Can someone explain?

Tags: java, annotations, big-o, code-snippets

What is the big-O notation of the given code snippet?

```
void snippet() { 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i=i+5)    
    a[i] = i;  
}
```

Comment: It is `n/5`, which is `O(n)`, so you are not wrong.

Comment: Care to explain what someone told you it should be?

Comment: The correct answer is T(n)=log O(n).

Comment: What is `log O(n)` supposed to mean? Do you mean `O(log n)`? But it is definitely **not** `O(log n)`, it is clearly `O(n)`: the work done is proportional to `n/5` which is proportional to n by a constant factor which is the definition for `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is O(n/5).

Let's take the simplified example (in javascript) below where n is 10

```
var n = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 5)
    console.log(i);
```

The loop will run twice.

```
First i is 0, 
then i is 5, 
then i is 10 and 10 < 10 == false so we stop.
```

Effectively we are moving i towards n in steps of 5.

Comment: But the correct answer is T(n)=log O(n). but still do not understand. how?